# Assigning Values to Variables from List in Python 2.7

Tags: python, pyodbc, xlrd

I'm trying to upload a decent amount (~300k rows) worth of data to a database using pyodbc. Since the data will need to be updated quarterly (from spreadsheets), what I'm trying to create is a sort of dynamic insert statement to make things a bit more streamlined. My thought process is that I can name the header of each column in the spreadsheets the same as the column in the table where I want the respective data to be uploaded.

What I've attempted to do is write a script that pulls out the column names in the header row on the worksheet and uses these as the variables, eliminating the need for me to change any code if I'm uploading different data from different excel sheets back to back:

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc


wb=xlrd.open_workbook(r"FILE")
worksheet = wb.sheet_by_name('SHEET_NAME')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows
num_cols = worksheet.ncols 
header_row = 0
header_list = [worksheet.row_values(header_row)]
header_values = ", ".join([str(i) for i in [cell.value for cell in worksheet.row(header_row)]])
question_marks = ",?" * (num_cols - 1) 
cell=worksheet.cell(1,1)

arr = []

for rowind in range(num_rows)[(header_row + 1):]:
    arr.append([cell.value for cell in worksheet.row(rowind)])

data = np.rec.fromrecords(arr, names=header_values)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXXXXXXXXX
\DEV_CON1;DATABASE=GGG;UID=AAA_dbo;PWD=XXXXXXXXX;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()



populate_db = "insert into tblSnap_TEST(" + header_values + ") values (?" + question_marks + ")"

for i in header_list: 
    i = data[i]

values = header_list 

cursor.execute(populate_db,values)

cursor.close
cnxn.commit
cnxn.close`
```

When I attempt to run the script I get the following error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-45-6809dc4a27ac>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('H:/My Documents/Python/string_search_test.py', wdir='H:/My Documents/Python')

File "C:\Users\xxxx\xxx\xx\x\Anaconda\lib\site-                                                    packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "H:/My Documents/Python/string_search_test.py", line 67, in <module>
cursor.execute(populate_db,values)

ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 21 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

The way I've done this before is by explicitly defining the values to be passed, such as:

`account_numbers = (sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value)`

But like I said, what I'm trying to do here is make it so I wouldn't have to type that out. That is what I was attempting to do with i = data[i]. I'm hoping there's a way for Python to recognize that "account_numbers" is in a list (created from the worksheet's headers), then grab the corresponding data based on something similar to `i = data[i]` which I tried above. Is a solution like this possible? data[i] does return the right data I want to insert into the table for each column, but it's not recognized by the execute statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not dealing with large Excel worksheets, or any problematic data types (such as one described in the section [Dates in Excel spreadsheets](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966)), you can simplify reading all rows into a single list, pop the header values for the insert columns, then call [Cursor.executemany](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemany) once to insert all values from the spreadsheet, passing a sequence of sequences for parameter values.

I've removed the numpy array population, since it's not necessary in the snippet provided.

```
header_row = 0

# build list of lists that represents row values in worksheet,
# including column names from header row
rows = [worksheet.row_values(row) for row in range(worksheet.nrows)]

# extract list of column names to use for insert statement, values to be inserted remain
columns = rows.pop(header_row)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXXXXXXXXX\DEV_CON1;DATABASE=GGG;UID=AAA_dbo;PWD=XXXXXXXXX;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# list of column names used to build SQL statement, including parameter placeholders (?)
populate_db = "insert into tblSnap_TEST ({}) values ({})".format(', '.join(columns),
                                                                 ', '.join('?' * len(columns)))

# insert is executed once for each sequence of parameter values
cursor.executemany(populate_db, rows)
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: It works, thank you! My worksheets have ~80,000 rows and take almost exactly an hour each to upload this way. Do you think looking into speeding up the process is worth it, or is this what I should expect?

Comment: Too many variables to estimate if that's a reasonable runtime for your environment. Isolate the spreadsheet read, measure how long it takes to populate the list without the database insert. Compare that against total runtime and see if the bottleneck is on client or database. There are probably some ETL tools that would be faster than a custom script if performance is a primary concern, but you may lose the flexibility of what you have working now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
cursor.execute(populate_db,*values)
```

this is known as unpacking a list (or other iterable)

Comment: This combined with `values = [data[i] for i in header_list]` will probably do it.

Comment: adding `values = [data[i] for i in header_list]` throws the original error I posted. However, adding just `*values` as you originally suggested seems like it may be working but also trying to insert the header row. It's tough to say for sure because the table immediately throws an error for the wrong data type though.